# ExtJS 4: Convert Grid To JSON for Storage in Database Or Converstion to PHP Object

Tags: php, json, grid, extjs4

I want to take an existing ExtJS 4 Grid and convert it into a JSON object for transport to the backend of my application (PHP). What do I need to do to make this happen? Do I simply need to overwrite the `getState` method of the grid and the `getColumnState` method of the column object?

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: Don't you mean the store, not the grid? Or are you talking about the state of the grid as it is displayed and not the underlying data?

Comment: I'm looking to send column information (headers, size, etc.,), sort order of the grid, and any filters applied to the store. So yeah, both the store and the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding the `getColumnState` for the column is a good idea. By default it assumes you'll be using the data with the same view again and that things like the column ids will be the same. I now have `getColumnState` returning an object that can be used as a config for a column. Add on whatever else you need from the grid and store as you find it useful.

I've found I need `text`, `dataIndex`, `hidden`, `draggable`, `hideable`, `resizable`, `minWidth` and `flex`. (And sometimes width).

Edit:
You want something like:

```
getColumnState: function () {
    return {
        text: this.text,
        ...
    };
}
```

Look at the original getColumnState to see what they do about grouped columns and width vs flex if you need those things.

Then just call `grid.headerCt.getColumnsState()`